# Explore inherited server

Tags: centos, linux

We have inherited a series of servers with a number of systems on them, all running CentOS.  A bunch of these are under-utilized and may not be doing much more than idling.  None-the-less, there is the possibility that a script or database is being accessed occasionally.  I would like to see exactly what these servers are doing--which scripts are being run and which databases are being accessed, etc.  How would you go about exploring an inherited system to see exactly what is being run/accessed?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bang for your buck will be to look at two things:

- What services are being provided?
- What jobs are running on a schedule?

**What Services Are Bring Provided**
You should be able to find most everything in two ways

- See what gets started by init with `chkconfig --list`. Look for anything labeled "on" and add to your list to be profiled.
- See what's actually listening on a port with `netstat -anut | grep 'LISTEN '. This will give you a list of all TCP/UDP ports in the listening state along with which binary opened them. Add those to your list to be profiled.

**What Scheduled Jobs Are Running**
This will involve looking at all the various and sundry cron jobs for anything non-standard. This one might take a bit longer since there are a lot more locations to look through.

- Look at all the executable files in `/etc/cron.(daily|weekly|hourly|monthly).
- Look at all, if any, files in `/etc/cron.d`
- Inspect all of the user crontabs in `/var/spool/cron`

Depending on what these two find, you may need to start digging more. For instance, if the service `httpd` is running, you will need to look in `/var/www` and `/etc/httpd` to figure out exactly *what* is being served up.

This kind of discovery can take a while, and be a lot of work. In the end, it's a great exercise. You will come out with a well exercised set of skills, and a pretty good understanding of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Running `ps -ef` would show current processes.

In a few terminals you could run these for a while: `top`, `iftop` and `iotop` these, respectively speaking, offer CPU, network and disk usage amongst other things.

Checking scheduling around cron's files and binaries/events mentioned in `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/secure` and `/var/log/syslog` should help too.